# Cannot stop label from accepting my touches

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I am working on a game where, when the user uses a skill, there is  a time limit before he can use it again. Say 5 seconds, so I have a button, and in the middle of that button is a label which count downs the seconds till I am able to use said skill again.

During testing i noticed that my skill didnt,  work since sometimes i would click the label node. Therefore i wrote

```
- (void)setupHUD
{
  int barHeight = 50;
  CGSize backgroundSize =
  CGSizeMake(self.size.width, barHeight);

 // myView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:myWhiteFloat alpha:myAlphaFloat];

  SKColor *backgroundColor =
  [SKColor colorWithRed:0 green:1 blue:0.0 alpha:0.4];

  SKSpriteNode *hudBarBackground =
  [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:backgroundColor
                               size:backgroundSize];

  [hudBarBackground setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
  hudBarBackground.position =
  CGPointMake(0, self.size.height - barHeight);
  hudBarBackground.anchorPoint = CGPointZero;
  [_hudLayer addChild:hudBarBackground];

      timeButtTimmer = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"Copperplate"];
      tbutttimmer.userInteractionEnabled=NO;
    //  [tbutttimmer setUserInteractionEnabled: FALSE];
        timeButtTimmer.name=@"label";
      timeButtTimmer.fontSize=15;;
      timeButtTimmer.position =
      CGPointMake(self.size.width-75,
                  self.size.height - 30);
      [_hudLayer addChild:timeButtTimmer];
      }
```

Much to my surprise the label is still clickable and my nslog confirms that i can click it, since i have an nslog of the name of the node i touched.

I have modified my code to read

```
 if ([node.name isEqualToString:@"button"] | [node.name isEqualToString:@"Readypras"])
```

I know this is dirty, but anyone has come across this before or am i doing something wrong. am i using the wrong property? thou in the documentation `userInteraction` is what sets if a node receives touch events.

```
-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size level:(int)level {
  if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {

        _hudLayer = [SKNode node];
        [_hudLayer setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
       [self addChild:_hudLayer];
        [self setupHUD];
     }
  return self;
}



- (void)createUserInterface
{
  SKLabelNode* startMsg =
  [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"Chalkduster"];
  startMsg.name = @"msgLabel";
  startMsg.userInteractionEnabled=NO;
  startMsg.text = @"Tap Screen to run!";
  startMsg.fontSize = 32;
  startMsg.position = CGPointMake(250, 150);
  [self addChild: startMsg];
}
```

Comment: You mean saying FALSE instead of NO? tried that...no change

Comment: The default for userInteractionEnabled is NO, so you must be setting it to YES somewhere. Check the logic around this, perhaps you are setting it to YES when you shouldn't.

Comment: This is the complete label code pasted above only thing missing is where i declared it in the implementation

Comment: Is `_hudLayer` an instance of `UIButton`? You may set the `userInteractionEnabled` property of `_hudLayer` to `NO`.

Comment: @mownier actully its an SKNode, i pretty much tried setting userInteractionEnabled to No everywhere i could. pretty odd in my opinion I may just have to leave it as is

Comment: One possibility is that the _hudLayer you're setting userInteractionEnabled on is not the one you have on screen. How and where are your controllers created? You need to put the code you posted into its context.

Comment: @rdelmar added more code

Comment: @rdelmar Look at the create userinterface method. I set userinteraction=no. If i touch it in NSLog like 
  NSLog(node.name); should it's name still appear?

Comment: No, I don't think it should, but I don't know what log you're talking about. Where do you have this log?

Comment: @rdelmar this code. NSLog(node.name) is in touchesbegan. if i Touch the startMsg I get msgLabel outputted in the log window.

Comment: I can't really tell what you're doing without seeing the code. If you want me to look at it, you can either upload it somewhere, or email the zipped up project folder to me, but otherwise I can't help.

Comment: @rdelmar Where can I email it or give you a drop box link

Comment: My email is rdelmar@comcast.net